# In Python, how can I read a yet-unknown number of lines from a txt file?

Tags: python, python-2.x

This is the use case. I have a text file potentially hundreds of thousands of lines long, where:
The first line contains the integer *N*, which is the number of following lines. I know how to read and convert the first line to an int; however, I have searched for a method to then read that number of lines from the file without success.

For example:
input.txt

```
4
foo
bar
carrot
snowflake
```

I will read and store the lines in variables. There are no blank lines.

How can I get the next *N* lines from my text file, preferably in a Pythonic way?

Comment: What do you want to do with the read lines?

Comment: @Anand I just need to read and store them in variables. Thanks, I'll edit that in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop with enumerate starting at 1 and break when the line number reaches the required number.

Example -

```
with open('<filename>','r') as f:
    file_list = []
    numlines = int(f.readline())
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        file_list.append(line.strip())
        if i >= numlines:
            break
```

Another way to do this using list comprehension and `file.readline()` -

```
with open('<filename>','r') as f:
    numlines = int(f.readline())
    file_list = [f.readline().strip() for _ in range(numlines)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), get the `n` using next to get the first line, then pass the `n` to islice to get the next `n` lines:

```
from itertools import islice

with open("in.txt") as f:
    n = int(next(f))
    lines = list(islice(f, n))
```

You can also just iterate over the islice object:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    n = int(next(f))
    for line in islice(f,n):
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    n = int(next(f))
    lst = [next(f).strip() for i in range(n)]
```

You could also choose to ignore the number of lines:

```
 with open('file.txt') as f:
    n = int(next(f))
    lst = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

In both cases:

```
>>> n
4
>>> lst
['foo', 'bar', 'carrot', 'snowflake']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use enumerate to traverse over lines and give index starting from 1 when the needed index is attained you could stop the iteration

```
with open("coursera.txt") as inp:
    check=int(inp.next().strip())
    print check
    for line,value in enumerate(inp,1):
        print line,value
        if line==a:
            break
```

**Output:**

```
4
1 apple

2 cab

3 daog

4 bad
```

To remove the extra new line you could `strip` the lines when printing or doing other things